# what's the alternate iproute2 for os x

Tags: linux, macos

Does [iproute2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.5/chapter06/iproute2.html) support os x?

There are some powerful tools in this package and I know that it requires the linux kernel.

What's the similar software like this special for the '[ss](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html)' package?

Or how to port it to os x?

Answer (score 0):

There's iproute2mac https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac

```
$ brew install iproute2mac
```